# Conversion of Java Web Project to Angular with Java

Tags: java, angular, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a Java web project with JSP as frontend and Java for backend. I want to convert this project to Angular Frontend and Java backend. I tried googling but didn't get anything. I am really stuck on how to do this.

Can anyone tell how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your project to MVC structure. May be you have separate service layer in your current project. Try to implement Controller layer. It will be better If you use REST controller. REST API is more suitable for Angular. You need to change bindings with JSP UI. Try to convert it with REST controller. And make service layer and dao layer separate. So Structure will be like this:

**UI->Controller -> Service->Dao**

I dont know your project is spring based or not. If spring based then you can covert your project with Spring boot project. There are many sample is now currently available for Spring based project.

If your project is not spring based you just need to implement **REST API** to your codebase and remove JSP bindings.